# Expose only a specific content type to Views

Tags: views

I've been playing with Views in trying to expose only a certain content type to the View, but I cannot find a way to do so.

For example:

I have a content type called `Regions` and I have 3 nodes of type `Regions`.

When I create my View, is there a way to only expose the 3 nodes of type `Regions`?

Currently, it displays all the entries in my `node` table, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add a filter to your view that is a content type filter, and then select "only show" and check off "Region" in the checkbox list.

So, edit your view, and on the left under "Filter criteria" click add.  Then, scroll through the list of available fields to filter on and find "Content: Type", check that off, click "Apply".  Then, on the left, select "Is one of" and on the right in the checkbox list select "Region", click "Apply".

After you've done that you can save your view.  The changes should be applied and should be showing only nodes in the view that are of type Region.

Comment: thanks I got it with your help. Another question, what is the difference between filter and contextual filter?

Comment: Eh, I have a basic understanding, but if you have a technical question like that it's wise to ask another question on Drupal Answers, that way it becomes searchable and thus more useful to others.  Only ask though after you've thoroughly searched for the answer.